# Find if two non-consecutive values are the same vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have one column of data with either "UP", "DOWN" or "" as values.  I am trying to write code that states that for all rows, if the first cell is "UP" then check the next rows until I come to either "DOWN" or "UP", i.e. if the next row has a "" then check the next row until I come to either a "DOWN" or "UP". 
I am very new to VBA, and have tried various options, but seem to only be able to bring back where there are consecutive "UP"s or "DOWNS" rather than where there is an "UP", a number of rows of "" and then another "UP".

This is my code:

```
    Range("z1:z250").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    For Row = 2 To 250
        If Range("Y" & Row).Value = "UP" Then
            For sRow = 3 To 250
                If Range("Y" & Row + 1).Value = "UP" Then
                    Range("Z" & Row) = "MT-UP"
                ElseIf Range("Y" & Row + 1).Value = "" Then
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried to add code such as `For Each c in Range (“Y3”:”Y250”)` but this doesn't make it find the next UP, and makes it very slow.  I have also tried `GoTo next cell` (although seem to understand this is frowned upon!) but this doesn't work either. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why all the code didn't appear in the blue box but it is all in my macro.

Comment: I did not follow you requirement. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve with this code. I am not sure but I think you can do this with a formula.

Comment: What do you want to happen after you find an "UP" or "DOWN"?

Comment: Sorry for clarification, if Y2 = "UP" then I would like to move down the Y column (Y3, Y4 etc) until I get the next row with either an "UP" or "DOWN" in the cell (the other cells have "").  If the first cell that I come to with something other than "" is "UP" then I want to enter "MT-UP" in Z2.  If the first cell I come to has "DOWN" I don't want anything entered in Z2, and I want it to move onto Y3.  Then if Y3 has "UP" it should look at Y4, Y5 etc. to see if "UP" or "DOWN" and if "UP" enter "MT-UP" into Z3.  Thanks so much for any assistance!

Comment: @Porcupine911 Sorry, just realised that I am meant to also add your usernames.  Completely new to this!

Comment: @L42 sorry answered your comment but didn't include your name in the post - apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear if this is what you want but take a look...

Instead of nested loops I used a flag to mark when a second consecutive "UP" was found before encountering a "DOWN". From your description it seems there's no need to check for empty cells ("").

```
Sub MTTest()

    Dim Row As Long
    Dim MTRow As Long
    Dim MTFlag As Boolean

    Range("Z1:Z250").ClearContents

    For Row = 2 To 250

        If Range("Y" & Row).Value = "UP" Then
            If MTFlag = True Then
                Range("Z" & MTRow) = "MT-UP"
                MTFlag = Flase
            Else
                MTFlag = True
                MTRow = Row
            End If
        Else
            If Range("Y" & Row).Value = "DOWN" Then MTFlag = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the Flag works well and speeds up the process a lot! However it doesn't do exactly what I was after - sorry, my description isn't great.  So, what I would like, is if cell Y2 is"UP" and Y3 is "UP" then Z2 is "MT-UP" - the code does this just now.  However, if Y2 is "UP" and Y3 is "", I want it to check Y4 to see if "UP" or "DOWN".  If Y4 is "" then I want it to check Y5, basically until it gets to the next "UP" or "DOWN".  If Y5 is "UP" (and Y3 is "", Y4 is "") then this also has "MT-UP" in Z2. I will try to add an excel to show easier.  thanks again!